# Fixed position for my Verbatim

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I use the `fancyvrb` package and I'd like that my `Verbatim` code is always written with 2pt indention. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you show us a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `\fvset{xleftmargin=2pt}` in the document preamble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by @egreg comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the [manual for `fancyvrb`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf)

### Section 4:

> Several verbatim environments are available, each with a lot of parameters to customize them. In the following examples we use the `Verbatim` environment, which is the equivalent of the standard `verbatim`. The parameters can be set globally using the `\fvset` macro or in an optional argument after the start of the environment.

### Section 4.1.13:

> `xleftmargin` (dimension): indentation to add at the start of each line (Default: 0pt — no left margin).

### Solution

Add, in your document preamble,

```
\fvset{xleftmargin=2pt}
```

Comment: Ok, let to say, I have a article document with leftmargin=20mm. And I would like, that any Verbatim listings will be started at \leftmargin position. How can I do that?

Comment: @DmitryVoronin What do you mean by “a document with leftmargin=20mm”?

Comment: I mean, that I set leftmargin as article parameter.

Comment: @DmitryVoronin How do you do it? What do you mean?

Comment: My problem is that I can't make Verbaim indention fixed, because I use Verbatim in another environment, like enumerate and so on, and I want, that those listings have no horizontal indention at all (always start at left page margin).

Comment: @DmitryVoronin Please, add a minimal example of what you mean to your question. A small, but complete document, showing the details. In my experiment, `Verbatim` respects the inner margin of enumerated lists.